# Demonstrate that: $\frac{1-a^2+c^2}{5c(3a+2b\sqrt{2})}+\frac{1-b^2+a^2}{5a(3b+2c\sqrt{2})}+\frac{1-c^2+b^2}{5b(3c+2a\sqrt{2})} \geq \frac{6}{5}$

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

**The question**

Let $a,b,c \in (0,\infty)$ with $a^2+b^2+c^2=\frac{1}{4}$. Demonstrate that:

$$\frac{1-a^2+c^2}{5c(3a+2b\sqrt{2})}+\frac{1-b^2+a^2}{5a(3b+2c\sqrt{2})}+\frac{1-c^2+b^2}{5b(3c+2a\sqrt{2})} \geq \frac{6}{5}$$

**The idea**

I just thought that if we get the first relation to equal 1 it would be very useful:

$4(a^2+b^2+c^2)=1=>\frac{1-a^2+c^2}{5c(3a+2b\sqrt{2})}+\frac{1-b^2+a^2}{5a(3b+2c\sqrt{2})}+\frac{1-c^2+b^2}{5b(3c+2a\sqrt{2})}=\sum \frac{3a^2+4b^2+5c^2}{5c(3a+2b\sqrt{2})}$

$\sum \frac{3a^2+4b^2+5c^2}{5c(3a+2b\sqrt{2})} \geq \sum \frac{3(a^2+b^2+c^2)}{5c(3a+2b\sqrt{2})}=\sum \frac{3}{20c(3a+2b\sqrt{2})}$

This is everything I could do... I thought of using Bergstrom or CBS to show the inequality...also I checked the case of equality and it doesn't happen when $a=b=c$  so the inequality of means isn't helpful.

I hope one of you can help me! Thank you!

Comment: Where did you find this question? It seems a bit odd to me how each fraction on both sides has a totally unnecessary factor of $5$ in the denominator

Comment: @MikeDaas I found it in one of my algebra books about inequalitys...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By AM-GM and Cauchy-Schwarz:

$$5c(3a+2b\sqrt{2})\le \left(\frac{5c+(3a+2b\sqrt{2})}{2}\right)^2\le (3a^2+4b^2+5c^2)\left(\frac{3+2+5}{4}\right)$$

Following your idea:

$$\sum \frac{3a^2+4b^2+5c^2}{5c(3a+2b\sqrt{2})} \geq \sum \frac{3a^2+4b^2+5c^2}{(3a^2+4b^2+5c^2)(\frac{3+2+5}{4})}=\frac{6}{5}$$